# Issues with left column moving to the top when greater width than 1440

Tags: css, wordpress, resolution

I have an established site using Wordpress and the Divi theme.  I have a menu on the left hand side. However if the screen is wider than around 1440 then this column is being shown above the page content.

This happens on every page where the column exists for example https://www.planninggeek.co.uk/planning/gpdo/article-4/

I have ruled out the menu, by replacing the shortcode with text.

I have looked at the CSS but can't see where it would work at 1440 x 900, but fail at 1600 x 1200

I am at a loss as to what the issue is.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the flaot attribute is responsible for your problem. Just remove this float:
[image]

If you add the float to the main-section of your aritcle and it's working like a charm:
[image]

But you still need to make some changes to the padding.